# Changing magnetic and electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, electric-fields

Does a changing electric field create 'constant' magnetic field or 'changing' magnetic

And , does a changing magnetic field create 'constant' electric field or 'changing' electric field

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the way it changes.

For example with light. A changing magnetic field creates a changing electric field which in turn creates a changing magnetic field and so on.

I am not sure if it is possible with a changing magnetic field to produce a constant electric field and vice-versa.

Comment: When we change the magnetic flux of a coil current is induced in it . Current induced, means there is electric field induced in a coil , so changing magnetic field create constant electric field . Am I right?

Comment: Pls answer that , can changing magnetic field create constant electric field or vice versa

Comment: I have developed this confusion because of electromagnetic wave , that you have mentioned in your 1st paragraph

Answer (score 1):

example of changing -> constant:

Change the magnetic field through an open loop at a constant rate and you will induce a constant electric field  between the open poles

Comment: Pls explain breifly , it was very short answer

Comment: And can you pls answer that comments which I have written on Fredrik ravn klausens answer